# how can we use proxy with NodeJS to download a blob from azure storage?

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage, http-proxy

I am having a .exe setup blob file stored in the container of azure storage. I am fetching the link  with the SAS token using the blob services in order to download the application on the client side. Now I want to use a NodeJS proxy server to make the api call from the link I am getting as response after using blob service method **getBlobToText()**. After hitting the link using the proxy I am getting a file downloaded on the browser side/client side but that file is getting corrupted after download and that to it is not having .exe extension.

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const http= require('http')
const app = express();
const fs=require('fs')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const server=http.createServer(app)

app.use(bodyParser.json())
  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.get('/subscription/launcher', function (req, res) {

  const url= res.url

  https.get(url, function (resp) {
    res.setHeader('Content-type', resp.headers['content-type']);
    res.setHeader('x-ms-blob-type',resp.headers['x-ms-blob-type'])
    res.setHeader('x-ms-request-id',resp.headers['x-ms-request-id'])
    res.setHeader('ETag',resp.headers['etag'])
    res.setHeader('Server',resp.headers['server'])
    res.setHeader('x-ms-lease-status',resp.headers['x-ms-lease-status'])
    res.setHeader('Last-Modified',resp.headers['last-modified'])
    res.setHeader('x-ms-version',resp.headers['x-ms-version'])
    res.setHeader('Content-Length',resp.headers['content-length'])
    resp.pipe(res);
  });

});

server.listen(9000,()=>{
    console.log('connected')
});
```

can anyone help me to understand why I am not getting the correct .exe extension file on download or is there any possible way to do it.

Comment: I tried to download from portal it shows me unconfirmed file and throws warning this type of file can harm your device but when i disregard it and click on keep it gets downloaded with proper extension.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be issue on Windows but not from Azure end as well as your code seems fine.

I tried to repro and found whenever I try to download files specific to .ps and .exe extension getting this warning.

[image]

[image]

So, for workaround i disregard it and click on keep it gets downloaded with proper extension.

[image]

Output –

[image]

Comment: thanks, yes that can be the reason

Comment: Hello @SumitSingh, If the answer was helpful, Could you please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem